# .htaccess redirect everything except

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS, except requests that are accessing my admin pages.

This should go to HTTP

```
  http://example.com/admin/**/*
```

This should go to HTTPS:

```
 http://example.com/blas.dfds
```

This is what I have, it will redirect everything to HTTPS. How to add filter to request that with "admin" keyword?

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

# http-https for everything except /admin
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# https-http for /admin
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Test this new set of rules in a new browser.